# SignalR ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, signalr

I want to subscribe on  but no work.

Check my code:

Service:

in ts:

```
 test() { return test }
```

in subscribe i see:

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
```

What is problem ?

Comment: seems like `this.hubConnection.on` does not return anything. Indeed, the callback is inside the `on` parameters, it does not return an Observable...

Comment: I agree but how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your code so that the data is pushed to an observable. Then you can subscribe to read it anywhere:

Service:

```js
hubMessage$ = new BehaviorSubject({});

public startConnection = () => {
    let token: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token") || '{}');
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://api/endpoint',
            { accessTokenFactory: () => token}) 
        .build();


    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
        .catch(err => { console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err) }) 

    this.hubConnection.on('message', (data) => { 
      this.hubMessage$.next(data);
    });
   
}
```

in ts:

```js
 private startHttpRequest = () => { 
    this.signalRService.hubMessage$.subscribe(
      (data: any) => console.log(data)
    )
 }
```

Comment: I'm not getting a message. I only see in network { type":6 }
{"type":6} 
{"type":6} 
{"type":6}

Comment: What this message type : 6 ?

Comment: if the `hubConnection.on("message")` event is being executed then it will push the data to `hubMessage$` subject. Then you would be able to subscribe to it. If the "message" event is not sending anything then you won't see anything. Are you sure `this.hubConnection.on('message')` works?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't even know how to test. Only on this first api connection do I get messages {type: 6} periodically? 

In console i see message 'Connection started'  and that is all

Comment: And this is also https://ibb.co/7rvcCdM 

that is all my ws network

Comment: I am very confused what is {"type":6} ???? I can't find answear on internet.... what is this ,why ? Maybe this is message ? binary ..oh

Comment: Emm, I'm not familiar with SignalR but maybe that's how your server sends those messages? :-) I'm just showing how you can pass the data with subjects from component to component

Answer (score 0):

You can either use @eko 's approach, or use a callback function like this:

Service

```
public addTransferChartDataListener = (callbackFn) => {
   return this.hubConnection.on('message', callbackFn);
}
```

Component

```
private startHttpRequest = () => { 
    this.signalRService.addTransferChartDataListener((data: any) => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting a message. I only see in network { type":6 } {"type":6} {"type":6} {"type":6}

Comment: What this message type : 6 ?

Comment: I suggest you to read `SignalR` documentation. And follow some guidelines, the `type: 6` that you a receiving is the default message that `SignalR` exchange to keep the connection alive.  Please, first read, and the try and ask...